# Why am I getting "TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null" when using getElementById?

Tags: javascript, function

In the following code:

```
function Transact() {
    if(document.getElementById('itctobuy').value!='') {
        itctobuy = parseInt(document.getElementById('itctobuy').value);
    }
    if(document.getElementById('steamtobuy').value!='') {
        steamtobuy = parseInt(document.getElementById('steamtobuy').value);
    }
    if(document.getElementById('reltobuy').value!='') {
        reltobuy = parseInt(document.getElementById('reltobuy').value);
    }
    if(document.getElementById('airtobuy').value!='') {
        airtobuy = parseInt(document.getElementById('airtobuy').value);
    }
    if(document.getElementById('bsnltobuy').value!='') {
        bsnltobuy = parseInt(document.getElementById('bsnltobuy').value);
    }
    updateValues();
}
```

The function's executed by a simple `onclick` of a button. There are 5 textarea elements and the user may input a number in any, and upon clicking the button the value should be stored in these vars if the textarea value isn't empty (Although it doesn't work even if the empty condition is not present).
If I remove the entire block, `updateValues()` executes fine, whereas putting it back causes it not be executed, so the problem's with it. What's the reason for this and how do I fix this?

Edit: The console says the following:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null at TRANSACT at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

So what's the cause of this error? It doesn't work when I input all text fields and their values are not null.

Comment: When you step through this code in your debugger, where/how specifically does it fail?

Comment: What is the scope of these variables?

Comment: All the variables are initially undefined and global.

Comment: Two observations: 1. It sounds a lot like at least one of those elements doesn't exist as of when that code is run, which means you should be getting an error in the browser console even if you don't use the debugger. 2. Those variables are declared somewhere, right? (If not, if you're in loose mode, the one(s) you assign to will become globals thanks to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html), but...)

Comment: Yes, but what is the scope of the variables?

Comment: Are there any errors in the developer console?

Comment: And with the update, you are trying to read the value of an input that does not exists so it throws an error

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes, the variables are defined, and don't all the elements exist as the code is run only when a button is clicked?

Comment: `document.getElementById('itctobuy')` = null, make sure you have an element with the id="itctobuy".

Comment: @Aryanpoonacha apparently one of those elements do not.... Typo in the id?

Comment: @Aryanpoonacha: Yes. Apparently at least one of those ID values is incorrect. The line number in the error message should be telling you which. Or, again, step through with the debugger.

Comment: Yes, one of the id names had a spelling error. Sorry about that, went through it meticulously but never noticed it. Should I delete this now? Will it be useful to anyone?

Comment: @Aryanpoonacha: I can't find a really good clean dupetarget for this common problem. Maybe we could make this a good clean example of it to use in future.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null`

That tells you that at least one of those elements doesn't exist as of when that code runs, so `getElementById` returns `null`, which you're trying to read the `value` property from.

`getElementById` will **only** return `null` if no element with the given ID exists in the document as of when you call it. In general, the reasons for the element not existing fall into these categories:

1. **Calling `getElementById` too early**
2. **Misspelling the `id`** (e.g., a typo)
3. **Using a `name` instead of an `id`**
4. **The element exists, but isn't in the document** *(rare)*

In your case, since this is on button click, it's probably #2 or #3. You can see which ID it's unhappy about by looking at the line the error identifies, or using your browser's debugger to step through the code statement-by-statement.

Let's look at each category:

### 1. Calling `getElementById` too early

One common error is to have code calling `getElementById` in a `script` block that's *before* the element in the HTML, like this:

```
<script>
document.getElementById("foo").innerHTML = "bar";
</script>
<!-- ...and later... -->
<div id="foo"></div>
```

The element doesn't exist as of when that code runs.

**Solutions**:

- Move the `script` to the end of the HTML, just before the closing `</body.` tag
- Put your call to `getElementById` in a callback, such as on the `DOMContentLoaded` event, or a button click , etc.

**Don't** use `window.onload` or `<body onload="...">` unless you really want to wait to run the code until **all** external resources (including all images) have been loaded.

### 2. Misspelling the `id`

This is really common, using `getElementById("ofo")` when the element is defined with `id="foo"`.

Example:

```
<div id="foo"></div>
<script>
document.getElementById("ofo").innerHTML = "I'm foo"; // Error
</script>
```

**Solution**: Use the right ID. :-)

### 3. Using a `name` instead of an `id`

`getElementById("foo")` looks for an element with `id="foo"`, **not** with `name="foo"`. `name` != `id`.

Example:

```
<input name="foo" type="text">
<script>
document.getElementById("foo").value = "I'm foo"; // Error
</script>
```

**Solution**: Use `id`, not `name`. :-) (Or look up the element with `document.querySelector('[name="foo"]')`.)

### 4. The element exists, but isn't in the document

`getElementById` looks *in the document* for the element. So if the element has been *created*, but has not been added to the document anywhere, it won't find it.

Example:

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.id = "foo";
console.log(document.getElementById("foo")); // null
```

It doesn't look throughout memory, it just looks in the document (and specifically, the document you call it on; different frames have different documents, for instance).

**Solution:** Make sure the element is in the document; perhaps you forgot to append it after creating it? (But in the example above, you already have a reference to it, so you don't need `getElementById` at all.)