# Angular Page wont load when using getElementById().value to obtain value of i18n input

Tags: angular, typescript, getelementbyid

**Details**: I am using i18n to localize my Angular site for Spanish speakers.

I can use controls[].value to get a value, but it is the one that was set in TypeScript, not the value that is in the actual DOM (translated by i18n). In other words, I can set "English" and in the PAGE itself, it will display "Ingles" but the console will still print "English"

**Problem**: When I use getElementById().value, the page just gets stuck on the Spinner.

**Some things I've tried**:

- I've tried testing with both hidden and non hidden elements
- I've tried it with div, i've tried it with input
- I've tried document.getElementById as well as document.getElementById
- As per [Why am I getting "TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null" when using getElementById?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40489919/why-am-i-getting-typeerror-cannot-read-property-value-of-null-when-using-ge) , I tried those steps, including separating it out into another method but that didn't help. I still get this error in console: TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null  <- it points directly to the getElementById

**TS**:

```
export class MyClass implements OnInit {
public unit: string;
_pFrm: FormGroup;

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

ngOnInit() {
   this.createForm();
}

createForm() {
    //form builder stuff here
    this._pFrm = this.fb.group({
    firstName: ["John"]
    english: ["English"]
    });

    console.log(this._pFrm.controls["firstName"].value);
    console.log(this._pFrm.controls["english"].value);

     const unit = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("testfield")).value
     console.log(unit); 
    }

}
```

**HTML**:

```
<mat-form-field class="input-width">
  <input matInput i18n-placeholder="@@PH_J7_11" placeholder="English" id="testfield" formControlName="english" i18n-value="@@PH_H9_12" value="English">
</mat-form-field>
```

**Goal**: I would like to be able to get the translated i18n value, which is in the DOM, to print to console. Instead it just gets stuck

Comment: You should probably avoid getting this value use DOM methods. Instead try using [FormControl](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl) to get/set the value of the respective control. Or even [Renderer2](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2) if you absolutely must use DOM methods.

Comment: Do you get any error in the browser's console? (F12)

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky I don't think this works with i18n... i18n for Angular is done in the HTML.

Comment: @Lynx242 yes, I get the "TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null <- it points directly to the getElementById" error, pointing at that line for getElementById. I tried separating it into another method, checking its properly named, etc.

Comment: Please, have a look at this page and the underlying stackblitz-link. Maybe this leads to a solution for you. https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/9350

Comment: I tried it in a barebones projcect and I got my code to work, but it won't work in my full project. I've tried building it piece by piece to be similar but it always just says TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null