# Why getting error when the element is set properly ? - TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

Tags: angular, typescript, null

**Goal**: Get value of HTML element in TypeScript (Angular)

**Problem**: Error: Uncaught (in promise): *TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null*

TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
    at UserRegistration2Component.push../src/user-registration-2.component.ts.UserRegistration2Component.getTranslations (user-registration-2.component.ts:649)
    at UserRegistration2Component.push../src/user-registration-2.component.ts.UserRegistration2Component.createForm (user-registration-2.component.ts:509)
    at new UserRegistration2Component (user-registration-2.component.ts:484)

*Code at line 649*:

```
    this.spanishHidden = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("hiddenInputLs")).value;
```

**Background/What i've tried**: I have done this same thing on dozens of other components/pages with no problem. I'm not sure why I am all of a sudden running into this error on this one. I've tried moving the hidden input element to different parts of the html but it has not changed the result. (Note: It's hidden because I am using i18n to translate and dont want these items to show on the page. Again, I've done this on dozens of other pages successfully) I also tried renaming the ID's and copy pasting them to make sure there was not some kind of misspelling or duplication, but still the same error.
I looked at the solution here and tried the possibilities but I'm still getting the error ([Why am I getting "TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null" when using getElementById?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40489919/why-am-i-getting-typeerror-cannot-read-property-value-of-null-when-using-ge) ). Am I missing something small like syntax?

**HTML**:

```
<mat-card class="login-card">



<mat-card-title class="text-center" i18n="@@Something_H1_1">
    New User Registration
</mat-card-title>
<mat-card-subtitle class="text-center" i18n="@@Something_H1_2">
    Step 1 of 4
</mat-card-subtitle>



<mat-card-content>
    <input placeholder="Spanish" id="hiddenInputLs" i18n-value="@@Something_H1_30" value="Spanish" [hidden]="true">
    <input placeholder="English" id="hiddenInputLe" i18n-value="@@Something_H1_31" value="English" [hidden]="true">

    <form [formGroup]="_userRegForm2" (ngSubmit)="cmdRegisterUser_click()" novalidate>

        <div fxLayout fxLayout.xs="column" fxLayoutAlign="center" fxLayoutGap="30px" class="columns">
            // more code here......
        </div>

    </form>
```

**Typescript**:

```
createForm()
    {
        this.getTranslations();
        this.languages = [
            { value: 'English', viewValue: this.englishHidden },
            { value: 'Spanish', viewValue: this.spanishHidden }
        ];
    }

getTranslations() {
    this.spanishHidden = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("hiddenInputLs")).value;
    this.englishHidden = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("hiddenInputLe")).value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things i would suggest looking at:

1. Never look directly into the DOM, prefer using interfaces provided by Angular, like Renderer or ViewChild.
2. Depending where the method `getTranslations` is being called from the view may have not yet been rendered. If called from the component constructor or ngOnInit hook the element wouldnt be yet created.
3. Never access directly the value of a searching method (getElementById) since its possible the element isnt available and JS engine would throw an error since its trying to access a property of a null variable, and finally would exit the stack execution and your app is open to problems. Prefer checking if the element exists before accessing its property.
4. It seems that at the template the line for english input has something that shoudnt be there, right at the end of it.

Let me know if after trying these few steps still have trouble extracting the value.

Comment: Thanks, @rafaelwalter In regards to #2, I ended up making ngAfterViewInit and called getTranslations from there. I set the variables to empty string initially so it could load. Not sure why I would have to do this as I've done what I had above on dozens of other pages with no problem ever.

Answer (score 0):

I had to put this in ngAfterViewInit(). To be honest, I'm not sure why this worked on all the other pages without ngAfterViewInit. But this is what I did:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.getTranslations();
}
```