# JS if statement

Tags: javascript

if the input is incorrect, the if statement counts it still like an correct one.

```js
var number1 = 1 * document.getElementById("inputNumber").value;
var numberx1 = document.getElementById("answer1").value;

function Count2() {
  if (number1 == numberx1) {
    var x1 = document.getElementById("answer1");
    x1.style.backgroundColor = "green";
  } else if (number1 != numberx1) {
    var x1 = document.getElementById("answer1");
    x1.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }
}
```

```html
<td><input type="number" id="answer1" onclick="Count1()" /></td>
<td><input type="number" id="answer2" onclick="Count2()" /></td>
```

Comment: You're setting the variables when the page is loaded, not when the user clicks on the inputs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why am I getting "TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null" when using getElementById?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40489919/why-am-i-getting-typeerror-cannot-read-property-value-of-null-when-using-ge)

Comment: @esqew The question doesn't say anything about an error message.

Comment: Put the variable assignments inside the function.

Comment: `function Count2() { var number1 = 1 * document.getElementById("inputNumber").value; ....`

Answer (score 0):

you are not getting the values onClick, the values are assigned before the click event,

Try doing something like this

```
//If number1 is dynamic make sure to p
//var number1 = 1 * document.getElementById("inputNumber").value;

function Count2() {
//If number1 is dynamic make sure to get it value
//var number1 = 1 * document.getElementById("inputNumber").value;
var numberx1 = document.getElementById("answer1").value;
  if (number1 == numberx1) {
    var x1 = document.getElementById("answer1");
    x1.style.backgroundColor = "green";
  } else if (number1 != numberx1) {
    var x1 = document.getElementById("answer1");
    x1.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to define Count1() method so the code knows what to do when the element with an id of answer1 has a valid function.

Answer (score 0):

**the problem was in variables, they need to go into the function:**

```
function Vypocet2(){

var number1 = 1 * document.getElementById("inputNumber").value;
var numberx1 = document.getElementById("answer1").value;

if(number1 == numberx1)
{
    var x1 = document.getElementById("answer1");
    x1.style.backgroundColor="green";
}

else if(number1 != numberx1)
{
    
    var x1 = document.getElementById("answer1");
    x1.style.backgroundColor="red";
}
}
```